# Using custom attribute to select multiple HTML elements

Tags: jquery

Lets say I want to select the "customAttribute" numbers that are greater than 2 but less than 5 so that I can change a CSS value via jQuery. I can't use the `:(ul)` `:(lt)` because the list is out of order so basically I want to do something like...

```
$(".class[customAttribute=' 3> 5< ']").css();
```

...except with proper syntax.

```
<div class="class" customAttribute="2"></div>
<div class="class" customAttribute="1"></div>
<div class="class" customAttribute="4"></div>
<div class="class" customAttribute="3"></div>
<div class="class" customAttribute="6"></div>
<div class="class" customAttribute="5"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 3; i < 5; i++) {
    $('.hello[customAttribute="' + i + '"]').css();
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop is essentially a `while` loop with an `i++` at the end ;)